# Adjust physical bounce of the emitter particles

Tags: particles, collision

I have set collisions for the object, but when the particles collide and bounce back, they look very rigid: how can I make it look more natural (like sparks)?

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Image (click for higher resolution) | Video (link to Youtube) |

Comment: Can you define 'rigid'? Do you want to add random rotation to the particles as they bounce off the sphere?

Comment: yes, i want to random rotation to the particles as they bounce. 
I have Particles' Rotation option turned on, but it rotates as soon as it is spawned, I want is that it only rotates when bounce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Rotation checked, set Randomize to `0`, and turn off all velocity in the Velocity segment, like this:

[image: Velocity and Rotation in the Particle Properties tab]

Now your particles should spawn based on the initial rotation of your blueprint object, and only rotate once they bounce off of something.

Comment: The more important setting here is _Dynamic_, which is disabled by default. This might work when bouncing of a sphere, but looking at the screenshot the particle objects are some kind of longish rods... if you let them fall onto a plane as floor, they will bounce around rotating, but they won't use their physical shape for these movements and not lay down flat in the end. They won't act like rigid bodies.